# data-toggle="pill" does not work after page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

In the code below, when the user clicks on the anchor tags goes to a Java action class and comes back to the same page, but the previously clicked link is not showing as an active tab. We pass the value of active tab as post parameter to the action class. How can we capture that back on the returned page and make the link active as it was before going to the action class.

here is the sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitTab(type) {
        if(document.myOrderForm.pagetype.value != type) {
            document.myOrderForm.pagetype.value=type;
            // The type is passed from the submitTab method on the anchor onclick event.
            document.myOrderForm.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The form  element is:

```
<form name="myOrderForm" method=post action="<c:url value="/LoadMyOrder.go" />" >
    <input type="hidden" name="pagetype" value='${requestScope.pagetype}'>
    // this hidden name pagetype gets set by the value from action class and
    // and is equal to one of the list items in the hyperlinks ('OO','CO' or 'CS')
    // if value of the page type equals to one of those above values i want to mark
    // the respective "LI" to class="active"

    // I think we need to do it on the -- $(document).ready(function() { 
    // but not quite sure. If some one donot understand  let me know.

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="pull-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="javascript:submitTab('OO')"; href="#" data-toggle="pill" >
                &nbsp;<b><fmt:message key="myorder.openorder" /></b>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="javascript:submitTab('CO')"; href="#" *data-toggle="pill"*>
                &nbsp;<b><fmt:message key="myorder.completedorder" /></b>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="javascript:submitTab('CS')"; href="#" *data-toggle="pill"*>
                            &nbsp;<b><fmt:message key="myorder.current.service" /></b>
                        </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Something like this I am thinking. I am new to bootstrap and jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageToGo = "${requestScope.pagetype}";
    alert("pageToGo is" +pageToGo);
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".nav li a:contains('OO')").parent().addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: can't you apply the appropriate class at server when you reload page?

Comment: $(document).ready( function() {
  //I want to achive some thing like this, but do not know why it is not working
  
  $(".nav li a:contains('${requestScope.pagetype}')").parent().addClass('active');
  
} )

Comment: just add the class in the html at server based on url

Comment: I am sending parameters as a post parameters not as querystrings in the links.

Comment: you know the page type at server regardless, therefore you know which button to add class to

Comment: @ charlietfl,  I am not following, can you give me some sample code.

Comment: $(".nav>li> a:contains('" + atext + "')").parent().addClass('active');

Comment: not sure why you just don't add the class on server